# Split csv cell into columns

Tags: csv, google-sheets

I'd like to split a csv column containing a dictionary-like structure/values into component columns. For example input/output data, see [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LXVWTdD96-ZjjmOLjfH1crPTAYFwRVk3wCVXWyaV0IY/edit?usp=sharing). Data will always come in that format ({"key":value,...}), with the number of key value pairs being arbitrary.

Not necessarily looking for a full solution here—more curious what the my options are for parsing data to create the output I want. Open to maybe using python to do some of this.

Answer (score 1):

use in B3:

```
=INDEX(BYROW(A3:A5, LAMBDA(x, IFNA(HLOOKUP(B2:E2, 
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRIM(FLATTEN(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(x, "[\}\{"",]", ), 
 CHAR(10)))), ":")), 2, 0)))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can use formula

```
=SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,""".*"":|\{|\}|\n|\r",""),",")
```

And here the result

[image: and here the result]